# How to change content of a special tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML :

```
<a class="static selected menu-item" href="/SitePages/Inbox.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">MyText</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a>
```

I want to find special text  (**MyText**) in this tag and then change the text.

I use this code but it doesn't work for me:

```
var divArray = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i<divArray.length; i++){
if (divArray[i].class="menu-item-text")
 return divArray[i].innerHTML;
}
```

How do I find this with JavaScript and change it?

Comment: You mean you want to change "Inbox" into something else? Re-read your question, it doesn't make sense (Find inbox of this tag). Also, you should show what you'be tried

Comment: Yes, I want special text of this tag.

Comment: It helps if you explain to us what you've tried so far, and what specific problem you're having with your approach. This makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *querySelectorAll* method, which is more widely supported than *getElementsByClassName* and can be more accurately targeted:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-text');
for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if ( (els[i].textContent || els[i].innerText) == 'Inbox') {
    alert('Found inbox');
  }
}
```

If you know you are looking for a span, then the selector can be `span.menu-item-text`. Note that qSA is only supported in IE 8 and 9 in standards mode, so make sure you have a DOCTYPE.

Here's a more robust solution that should work in any browser back to IE 6 or earlier:

```
function getEl(className, text) {
  var els, t, re;
  var result = [];

  // Get elements matching the class
  // Try qSA
  if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    els = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);

  // Try gEBCN
  } else if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  // Try gEBTN
  } else if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
    t = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)'); 
    els = [];

    for (var i=0, iLen=t.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (re.test(t[i].className)) {
        els.push(t[i]);
      }
    }

  // Stop here if everything failed.
  } else {
    return;
  }

  // Go looking for element with matching text
  for (var j=0, jLen=els.length; j<jLen; j++) {

    if ( (els[j].textContent || els[j].innerText) == 'Inbox') {
      result.push(els[j]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

JS:

```
var inbox = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-text");
if(inbox.length > 0){
    inbox[0].innerText = "New Text";
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="static selected menu-item" href="/SitePages/Inbox.aspx">
    <span class="additional-background">
        <span class="menu-item-text">Inbox</span>
        <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

​

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d39T2/)

Comment: I use (document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-text")) , but don't return any element for me .

Comment: @ar.gorgin does the demo work for you?